# angularjs mock markdown file

Tags: angularjs, markdown

There is a legacy angularjs project.I find that using markdown file as mock.
for example.`verify-session.POST.md`

````
# 检验token是否合法

### Api url

/verify-session

### request

```js
//
{
  type: 'verify-session',
  requestSystem: 'sdkportal',
  ts: '20150405060404',
  accessToken: 'dfdfdgfdh',
  sign: 'wefergrthyukiuliodfrhtyjyupo'
}

```
````

In the file, there is many compile error showing by red underline.But i can't figure out the reason.

Then when i start to debug the page,run `gulp` command,it show the error and `chrome Developer Tools` show error too.
Please help me,thanks!

Comment: That looks like valid (more or less) Markdown. Are you trying to edit it a something else when you see the compile errors? What parts of the file are marked as errors?

Comment: @Chris when i edit file and save it, but it is no effect.These error appear in`# 检验token是否合法`,````js`

Comment: What editor are you using? And what kind of file does it think you're editing (Markdown or something else)? Where do those errors appear?

Comment: atom, markdown file in mock directory. Compile error appear in `verify-session.POST.md file etc. In windows cmd and chrome developer tool showing error: `Error: Line 5: Unexpected token :` correspond to the location of file

Comment: Why would you look at a Markdown file in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: The error in browser's developer tools is occur when i run `gulp`,then open the browser. The browser's page is padding because the mock data is not loaded correctly.Even i run `bower install` and `npm install`,but it is not work.

Comment: Oh. So your Gulp task isn't doing what it's supposed to do. Please [edit] your question and add details about that (what the task is trying to do, any libraries it uses; probably just include your entire `gulpfile.js`).